# How can I get all sequences bound with a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, django, postgresql, sequences

I recently switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL in my Django app and I need to set last values of all sequences on max. number of corresponding table and column. How can I get all sequences related to a table? So far I am doing somethign like:

```
SELECT sequence_name FROM information_schema.sequences 
WHERE sequence_name LIKE 'table_name%';
```

but I dont't like this approach, mostly because I have to additionally clean the results. Is there some ID that connects table with their sequences.

Now I can't add any object to my database, because Postgre "auto increment" is running from 1 and new objects' PKs are clashing with existing records.

Note: My django app is quite large and I am using several additional package, so the naming convention is not consistent (table names are with / without app pefix, PK columns are like 'tableid' or 'table_id' of just 'id' and so on)

Comment: [Deleting a table in PostgreSQL without deleting an associated sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328884/deleting-a-table-in-postgresql-without-deleting-an-associated-sequence) has good answers that are applicable to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset <appname>
```

and feed that to `psql` cli

HTH

Comment: THX, thats exactly what I needed (though not what I asked for :-D)

Comment: @Maddog wow, so I can understand needs that lie beyond questions!

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're not doing anything too unusual, try the following two queries.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences ;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_default LIKE 'nextval%';
```

That should tell you what you need to know. I'd probably just strip the sequence-name out of the `column_default` field.

Comment: THX, thats exactly what I asked for (though not what I needed :-D)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the sequence name along with count.

```
SELECT sequence_name,start_value from information_schema.sequences;
```